# ios meta: how do I get rid of an ugly daisy

Tags: ios, swift

```
public protocol NodeProtocol
{
    var identifier: String? { get }
    ...
}

var node: (NodeProtocol)?

required public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws
{
    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    do {
        node = try values.decode(Operation.self, forKey: .node)
    } catch {
        do {
            node = try values.decode(Deposit.self, forKey: .node)
        } catch {
            do {
                node = try values.decode(Loan.self, forKey: .node)
            }
            catch {
                    print ("failure \(error) decoding node")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How could I fold this ugliness into a loop dumping Foo.self into an array?

```
public class BVOperation: Codable { ...
public struct Loan: Codable { ...
public struct Deposit: Codable { ...
```

if you try something like this:

let types = [Operation.self, Loan.self, Deposit.self] as [Any]

```
let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
for type in types {
    do {
        node = try values.decode(type as! (NodeProtocol)?.Type, forKey: .node)
        break
    } catch {
        continue
    }
}
```

[image: you'd get the infamous Value of protocol type 'NodeProtocol' cannot conform to 'Decodable'; only struct/enum/class types can conform to protocols]

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to have a type key in your serialized data, but if that's not possible, you could achieve some better looking code by doing something like this:

```swift
    let types = [Operation.self, Loan.self, Deposit.self]

    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    for type in types {
        do {
            node = try values.decode(type, forKey: .node)
            break
        } catch {
            continue
        }
    }
```

Also, you are not required to use `do ... catch` blocks if you don't like them. You can make use of optional binding instead:

```swift
    let types = [Operation.self, Loan.self, Deposit.self]

    let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    for type in types {
        guard let decoded = try? values.decode(type, forKey: .node) else { continue }
        node = decoded
        break
    }
```

They'll do the same, but it's a matter of preference.

Comment: yes, that's how I've tried to tackle it. Sadly it does not compile. I should've been more explicit in my question. Updated the question.

Comment: Yup, indeed checked and does not work. I'll check again and update my answer if I find something. All you can do meanwhile is to use optional binding approach which gets rid of arrow code, but you have to write one more line of code whenever you have a new type to handle. This whole deserialization should be done using a type key in your serialized data, so if you have any chance to do it like that, I strongly suggest to do so. That should be the way to go. Thrown errors/exceptions should occur only when the errors really do exist, not as a business logic handling mechanism.